# Creating a chart related to excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, scatter-plot

I am totally new to VBA. Trying to put together the following code: there is a data set with multiple risks. User clicks the command button, a message pops up "please select a risk to be graphed", user selects a risk from the database (one from the column E). After that everything is automized: a scatter graph is inserted, three values for x-axis are chosen (they are in the columns J,K,L in the same row as the selected risk),three vaues for the y-axis are 0, value from the column P in the same raw as the rist, 0. After the graph is plotted and formatted. Formating is pretty easy, I am so far stuck with the first part. Here is what I have so far. The error comes on the line witch selects x-values, "the element with this name was not found". The line is marked **

```
Sub Makro2()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range
    Set InputRng = Application.Selection
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Choose the risk to draw", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    **ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Tabelle1!Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7))"**
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=0; Tabelle1!ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11);0"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select

    With Selection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    End With

    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found an alternative solution by using a combo box. An example is here http://excelribbon.tips.net/T007887_Automatically_Creating_Charts_for_Individual_Rows_in_a_Data_Table.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antony,

You don't have to treat this as if you are assigning a formula to the cell / XValues property - right now you are essentially assigning a string and expecting Excel to evaluate that as a formula. Instead, it should be simply assigned using ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Tabelle1") to refer to the worksheet -

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7))
```

The second line expects an Array / Range of cells to be passed try followng-

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Array(0, ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11),0)
```

More details here -

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838988.aspx

Comment: Thanks, ssaptarshi. Will try your suggestion